# should query inside must elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am new to elasticsearch query DSL, I have documents in my ES index as below

```
{
    "doc_id":1,
    "city_id": 1,
    "name": "test1",
    "vvip": false
},
{   
    "doc_id":2,
    "city_id": 1,
    "name": "test2",
    "vvip": false
},
{   
    "doc_id":3,
    "city_id": 1,
    "name": "test3"
}
{
    "doc_id":4,
    "city_id": 1,
    "name": "test4"
}
{
    "doc_id":5,
    "city_id": 1,
    "name": "test5",
    "vvip": true
}
{
    "doc_id":6,
    "city_id": 1,
    "name": "test6",
    "vvip": true
}
```

For doc_id 3 and doc_id 4 vvip field does not exist

I want to form a query in such a way that these documents should always be returned if I query for vvip:true or vvip:false

Meaning for query city_id=1 and vvip=false 
response will contain doc_id 1,2,3,4 
for city_id=1 and vvip=true 
response will contain doc_id 3,4,5,6

I tried below query but it did not help

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "city_id": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "vvip"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "city_id": "1"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "vvip": false
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simplify your query like this, which should work as you expect :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city_id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "vvip": true
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "vvip"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query mean you match `city_id=1` **AND** (`vvip=true` **OR** `vvip` *not exist*).